# Why can't select a mat-option of mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I create a Dialog to insert data:

this is html page:

```
<input type="hidden" ngModel="{{au.id}}" name="id">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="au.name" name="name">
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Sex</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="au.sex" name="sex">   
      <mat-option [value]="nam">Nam</mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="nu">Nu</mat-option> 
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Birth Day</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="date" [(ngModel)]="au.birthDay" name="birthDay">
</mat-form-field>
<br />
<button mat-raised-button (click)="Save()">save</button>
```

This is ts file:

```
export class Author {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  sex: string;
  birthDay: Date;
}
export class Author_PopupComponent {
  au: Author = new Author();
}
```

`mat-select` show 2 value, but i choose a option, it can't display value was selected in control.

Why can't select a `mat-option` of `mat-select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

Replace `[value]` with `value` in your `<mat-option [value]="nam">Nam</mat-option>` when your value is not dynamic.

**Method 2**

Surround your mat-option value (string) with single quote while using `[value]`, to treat it as dynamic value.